# AngularJS form field is dirty and invalid when page loads on IE10 only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple login form which on IE10 always has the form fields invalid when the page loads without the user doing something.

The form fields are really simple:

```
<input type="text" required class="input-block-level" placeholder="username" ng-model="username" name="username" tabindex="1">
<p class="text-error" ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.username.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">required</span>
</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DNUanGGaZDgFWYrm3gLK?p=preview

In the plunker above you can reproduce the issue by focusing on the field while inside my app the error field is displayed when the page loads. In other browsers it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sunnycyk/5603832) for this, which I've reproduced below with all the necessary boilerplate:

> **angular-hacks.js:**

```
(function (window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var hacks = angular.module('hacks', []);
    hacks.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$sniffer', ['$delegate', function ($sniffer) {
            var msie = parseInt((/msie (\d+)/.exec(angular.lowercase(navigator.userAgent)) || [])[1], 10);
            var _hasEvent = $sniffer.hasEvent;
            $sniffer.hasEvent = function (event) {
                if (event === 'input' && msie === 10) {
                    return false;
                }
                _hasEvent.call(this, event);
            }
            return $sniffer;
        }]);
    }]);
})(window, window.angular);
```

I haven't had any problems with this so far, although I won't pretend that I've put it through any serious regression testing. It's filtering out *all* the input events for IE10 and might need to be made more specific.

Comment: I will test it, thanks! It seems the issue with the field being invalid on page load was caused by one of my directives. But the focus error still stands.

Comment: @lucassp: The behaviour is reproducible with no custom directives whatsoever, and goes away as soon as you take out the placeholder. It's actually a [known issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2614). The problem is not that it is marked invalid - that's by design - the problem is that it is also marked dirty, which is only supposed to happen when you type in the field.

Comment: @Aaronaught I've taken out the placeholders on my inputs, yet they are still marked as invalid on page load, and that in turn causes my error css classes to be applied on page load. Any fix? :(

Comment: Never mind, it was because I hadn't added `&& formName.property.$dirty` to my conditional `ng-class` :)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

Add `ng-if="true"` to the input element.

Tested only on angular 1.2.28.